# How can I run rest of code only if function

Tags: javascript, jquery

As the title says how can I run rest of code (which is below the main function), only when some condition is done? For example:

```js
function foo() {
   count = 0;
   var interval = setInterval(function() {
      count++;
      if (count == 10) {
         clearInterval(interval);
   console.log('Done');
      }
   }, 1000);
}

foo();

console.log("It should display after Foo() is done");
```

Comment: put it in the `if (count == 10)` or put it in a function and execute that function in the if statement. Or you can use promises. Or you can wrap the whole code in an async function, still use promises, but then await those promises.

Comment: Well it was just an example, it can be also a function instead of that console.log But i want to run the function/console.log something only when foo hit 10

Comment: Use a Callback or Promise ->
[Asynchronous Programming :: Eloquent JavaScript](https://eloquentjavascript.net/11_async.html)

Comment: @Andreas Well its kinda deep water for me atm, but ill try. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use `promise` for this.. Then Your code will be something like this

```
  function foo() {
      return new Promise(function(resolve , reject){

       count = 0;
       var interval = setInterval(function() {
          count++;
          if (count == 10) {
             clearInterval(interval);
             console.log('Done');
              resolve();
          }
       }, 1000);
       })

    }

    foo().then(function(){

    console.log("It will be displayed after Foo() is done");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the `console.log` in a function and then can call the function once the condition is met.

In the solution below, `console.log` will get triggered after 10 secs.

```js
function foo() {
  count = 0;
  var interval = setInterval(function() {
    count++;
    if (count == 10) {
      clearInterval(interval);
      console.log('Done');
      execAfterFoo(); // Will execute after the condition is met
    }
  }, 1000);
}

foo();

function execAfterFoo() {
  console.log("It should display after Foo() is done");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing `foo` with `setInterval`. The call to `foo` is actually "done" before the console log. What I think you might mean is "it should display after the condition in the function in `setInterval` is met."

In that case, there are several ways to do it, the simplest probably being just wrapping the functionality you're interested in, as void demonstrates in his answer. Another way might be to use [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) or another kind of async flow.